# Share variables to included templates in django

Tags: django

In `views.py` the `thing` object is being passed to `index.html`.

```
def index(request):                              
    return render(request, "myapp/index.html", {
        'things': Thing.objects.all()            
        })
```

`index.html` is setup like this:

```
{% block body %}                               

    {% for thing in things %}
        {{ thing.attribute }}
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I would like to separate the html that renders the modal referred to by the button into another html file to keep things organized. I was able to do this by referencing the modal html file with `include` as shown below:

```
{% block modal_code %}                    
    {% include 'myapp/modal_code.html' with things=things %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I tried to share the `things` object it didn't get incorporated into `modal_code.html` when I used it like this:

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {{ thing.attribute }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation, you can pass context like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}
```

so in your case:

```
{% block modal_code %}                    
    {% include 'myapp/modal_code.html' with things=things %}
{% endblock %}
```